# C-S-a doesn't select text to the line beginning

Tags: key-bindings, debugging, region, selection

The Key combination `Ctrl + Shift + a` doesn't work in my GUI-Emacs to select a region from the position of pointer to the line start. Doing `C-h k` and the above key combination shows no documentation.

Comment: Do you see this when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If so, use `M-x report-emacs-bug`, providing a step-by-step recipe to reproduce it. If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. (I don't see what you report with `emacs -Q`.)

Comment: Do you have `shift-select-mode` deactivated? On Emacs-26 I see a documentation for `C-h k C-S-a`.